# Problem with generating one extra slide using PHP FOR loop in Laravel Blade

Tags: php, html, laravel, laravel-blade

I have a strange problem in Blade. I think is something obvious but I'm just stuck at it.

I have a Bootstrap carousel with cards in Larvel Blade view. I'm creating new "carousel-item" (slides) using if in for loop, but I'm facing the problem that it generates one empty slide. I cant figure it out why this is happening.
The following code should generate 2 slides with 4 cards in it. Unfortunately it creates 3 slides the last of them empty.

This is my code:

```
<div id="carousel{!! $type !!}" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel" data-touch="true">
                <div class="carousel-inner">
                    <div class="carousel-item active">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center latest__properties_row">
                            @for($i=0;$i<=7;$i++)
                                @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]))
                                    <div class="col-md-3 mb-3 latest__properties">
                                        <div class="card">
                                            @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['photos']))
                                                @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['photos'][0]))
                                                    <a href="/properties/{!! $latest[$type][$i]['slug'] !!}"><img
                                                            class="img-fluid latest__properties__photo"
                                                            alt="{!! $latest[$type][$i]['title'] !!}"
                                                            src="/images/properties/{!! $latest[$type][$i]['photos'][0]['url'] !!}"></a>
                                                @endif
                                            @endif
                                            <div class="card-body">
                                                <div class="title">
                                                    <a href="/properties/{!! $latest[$type][$i]['slug'] !!}"><h4
                                                            class="card-title">{!! $latest[$type][$i]['title'] !!}</h4>
                                                    </a>
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- Slide like buttom -->
                                                <button class="slide__like-btn">
                                                    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>
                                                </button>
                                                <!-- Slide badge -->
                                                @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels']))
                                                    @for($k=0;$k<=count($latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels']);$k++)
                                                        @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels'][$k]))
                                                            <div class="slide__badge {!! ($latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels'][$k]['attributes'] != '' || $latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels'][$k]['attributes'] != null) ? $latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels'][$k]['attributes'] : '' !!} text-uppercase">
                                                                {!! $latest[$type][$i]['terms']['property_labels'][$k]['name'] !!}
                                                            </div>
                                                        @endif
                                                    @endfor
                                                @endif
                                                <ul>
                                                    @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['rooms']) && $latest[$type][$i]['rooms'] != 0)
                                                        <li><b>Стаи:</b> {!! $latest[$type][$i]['rooms'] !!}</li>
                                                    @endif
                                                    @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['bathrooms']) && $latest[$type][$i]['bathrooms'] != 0)
                                                        <li><b>Бани:</b> {!! $latest[$type][$i]['bathrooms'] !!}
                                                        </li>
                                                    @endif
                                                    @if(isset($latest[$type][$i]['sqm']) && $latest[$type][$i]['sqm'] != 0)
                                                        <li><b>Квадратура:</b> {!! $latest[$type][$i]['sqm'] !!} m²</li>
                                                    @endif
                                                </ul>
                                                <p class="latest__properties__id">
                                                    ID: {!! $latest[$type][$i]['unique_code'] !!}</p>
                                                <p class="latest__properties__price">
                                                    <span class="euro">€ {!! $latest[$type][$i]['price'] !!}</span>
                                                    <span
                                                        class="bgn">{!! $latest[$type][$i]['price_bgn'] !!} лв.</span>
                                                </p>
                                                <p class="latest__properties__created__at">
                                                    {!! $latest[$type][$i]['created_at'] !!}
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                    @if($i == 3)
                                    </div>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="carousel-item">
                                    <div class="row justify-content-center latest__properties_row">
                                    @endif
                                @endif
                            @endfor
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="carousel-item">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center latest__properties_row">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: You should start looking into sub-views to make your code more readable

Answer (score -1):

I just figured it out... I was looking like 1000 times the code and that I realize I just forgot an empty slide right after the for loop.

Comment: Questions that are the result of typographical or other errors are not on topic. Instead of answering the question, please delete it.